# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after adding dependences

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, libvlc

I have an application to which I tried to import vlclib, the application is runing without problem but as soon as I add the library, the application stops working. The strange thing is that once added the library (I tried using "aar" file and also via repository I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` but not for the class in the library but for the classes I already have in my application.
If I remove the activity which point to the new library but I leave the library in dependencies everything works fine.

What can cause this problem?

UPDATE:

I tried again and the error is still the same:
I rolledback to the working version and i tried:
Import the library again as gradle dependence and the application is still working, then when i add some reference to the imported library (not in the main activity but on a secondary one the application does not start anymore giving me the following error :

> 12-21 13:17:14.674 30816-30816/com.pecana.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pecana.example/com.pecana.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class com.pecana.example.SlidingTabLayout
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class com.pecana.example.SlidingTabLayout
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>                                                                               at com.pecana.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:162)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>                                                                               at com.pecana.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:162) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pecana.example.SlidingTabStrip
>                                                                               at com.pecana.example.SlidingTabLayout.(SlidingTabLayout.java:102)
>                                                                               at com.pecana.example.SlidingTabLayout.(SlidingTabLayout.java:89)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
>                                                                               at com.pecana.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:162) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   12-21 13:17:14.799 30816-30816/com.pecana.example I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30816 SIG: 9

UPDATE 2:
By removing some dependencies the application starts again so i guess it was related to the 65000 methods limit. But how to bypass this limit?
I Mean, I have many integration to be done in my application and i will reach it soon again.

Thank you

Comment: please add your `build.gradle` and logcat of error

Comment: what is `multidex` configuration of your project?

Comment: Portion of the config: defaultConfig {
...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
   
}

dependencies {
...
   
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
   ...
}

Comment: Are you working with Proguard minify ?

Comment: Looking at config it seems not : minifyEnabled false    but I don't know the meaning of this

Comment: It's to obfusucate your code so it's less readable when you decompile an APK. But when you add libraries and you use minify you need to keep the libraries and don't obfusucate them otherwise it can generate errors such as NoClassDefFound error. You could also try to rebuild /clean project.

Comment: I'm trying to clean and rebuild it even if I already tried. I'll let you know and post log

Comment: @thepoosh I added the log and some info if you can help.

Comment: It seems like there is no definition for com.pecana.example.SlidingTabLayout. did you add all the relevant constructors?

Comment: Yes it's a simple class and it is working perfectly before adding libray.